# how to merge several csv files in R by columns without loading them into memory completely

Tags: r

imagine that I have a huge matrix (toy example)

```
dat <- matrix(1:100,ncol = 10) 
colnames(dat) <- paste0("X",1:ncol(dat))
dat
      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
 [1,]  1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81  91
 [2,]  2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82  92
 [3,]  3 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83  93
 [4,]  4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84  94
 [5,]  5 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85  95
 [6,]  6 16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86  96
 [7,]  7 17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87  97
```

this matrix is divided into `columns` and written in several files

```
path <- paste0(getwd(),"/example/")
dir.create(path = path)
colum_id <- matrix(1:10,ncol = 2,byrow = T)
for(i in 1:nrow(colum_id)) write.csv(dat[,colum_id[i,]], file = paste0(path,i,".csv"), row.names = F)
```

files in a folder
dir(path)

```
[1] "1.csv" "2.csv" "3.csv" "4.csv" "5.csv"
```

.. read files

```
paths <- paste0(path,dir(path))
lapply(paths , \(Path) head(read.csv(Path),2) )

[[1]]
  X1 X2
1  1 11
2  2 12

[[2]]
  X3 X4
1 21 31
2 22 32

[[3]]
  X5 X6
1 41 51
2 42 52

[[4]]
  X7 X8
1 61 71
2 62 72

[[5]]
  X9 X10
1 81  91
2 82  92
```

The question is, how can I combine in `R` all these files  column by column without loading them completely into memory (because the files are very large) to get the whole file on disk as a result.

Comment: a couple of questions: 1. are you wanting the output to be a csv file, and 2. if yes, then what is the purpose of a csv file you can't load?

Comment: This does seem like a case where a small (SQL?) database might do the job.

Comment: @Mark 
1) desirable but not required
2) i can load it with an `arrow` for example

Comment: Without R, if you have access to bash try: `paste -d "," *.csv > newFile.csv`

Comment: @ Paul Stafford Allen
can you show an example here please

Comment: @ zx8754
I don't have access to `bash`  I'm interested in the solution from `R`

Comment: @zx8754 you could probably rig together something with system2() if you wanted? :-) would just have to check OS

Comment: @Mark yes, task is better suited outside R. Or within R, detect system and use "if else" to run within system2 that is compatible with OS.

Comment: @mr.T are you asking, 1) how to do this without loading **all** individual input files (e.g. `1.csv`, `2.csv`) into memory all at the same time, or 2) how to do this without loading **any** individual input file into memory at one time?

Comment: @ SamR   I prefer option 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Appending a column means writing to the middle of a `csv` file

Appending columns makes sense in a [columnar data format](https://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2019/11/21/guide-to-columnar-file-formats.html) such as SQL or [arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/). The suggestion in the comments to use SQL is a good one and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53001026/12545041) is an answer using [`RSQLite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/vignettes/RSQLite.html) which does this.

In a row-based format, like `csv`, appending a column is essentially writing to the middle of a plain text file. This means loading the file from (at best) somewhere on the first line, and re-writing everything after that point.

### Append rows to a `csv` file instead

The best way to write a large plain text file, without loading the entire contents into RAM, is one line at a time. In your case, that means:

1. Read one row at a time from each of the input files.
2. `cbind()` each piece of the row to make a complete row.
3. Write the row out as either (in the case of the first row) the first line of a new text file, or (for subsequent rows) a line appended to an existing text file.

This would simply be:

```r
outfile <- "./example/big_out_file.csv"
N_ROWS <- 11
for (i in seq(0, N_ROWS - 1)) {
    line <- do.call(
        cbind,
        lapply(paths, \(f) read.table(f, sep = ",", skip = i, nrows = 1))
    )
    write.table(line, outfile, col.names = FALSE, append = TRUE, sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)
}
```

The key is setting `append = TRUE` to [`write.table()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/write.table), to append one line at a time to the existing text file (or to create it where it does not exist).

I set `N_ROWS` to `11` here as we know the input had `10` rows and a header. If you do not know how many lines there are, you can check without reading the file into memory by using [`fpeek::peek_count_lines()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fpeek/versions/0.1.1/topics/peek_count_lines) to check the number of lines in the first chunk, i.e:

```r
N_ROWS  <- fpeek::peek_count_lines(paths[1])
```

Or if you prefer there are other approaches in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691133/counting-rows-with-fread-without-reading-the-whole-file).

This approach has the advantage of not loading **any** of the input files into memory at once, which you indicated in the comments was your preference. It reads one line of each input file at a time. This means there are a lot more read operations, so it will be much slower than reading each file once, but that's the trade-off. Depending on your memory constraints, you may be able to speed things up by reading more than one line at a time. If you do this, make sure to read and write the header separately to avoid the following rows being coerced into `character`.

### Output

We can check that, when read back in, the output is the same as `dat`, the original matrix:

```r
m <- as.matrix(read.csv(outfile))
head(m, 2)
#      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
# [1,]  1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81  91
# [2,]  2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82  92
identical(dat, m) 
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks!
can you take a look at a similar question about `arrow`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76868729/how-to-read-out-of-memory-a-large-matrix-with-an-arrow-package-r

Comment: @mr.T why not just `read_csv_arrow(outfile, as_data_frame = FALSE)` on the file we have created here?

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to do this directly from the arrow